# Java -cp on linux

Tags: java, linux

I made a program which runs fine on windows. When I moved it over to CentOS, I got this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.wbc.WBCController

This is the file setup and .sh on linux:
[image: linux]

And this is the file setup and .bat on windows:

[image: windows]

Does anybody know what the problem is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: is wbc.jar the executable?

Comment: Are you sure that the filename has the right case? WBC.JAR would not be the same as wbc.jar  on Linux. Or that the class may have a different case?

Comment: Try removing the quotes around `"wbc.jar"`, they are not necessary.

Comment: Use `jar tvf wbc.jar` to verify that `org.wbc.WBCController` is in the JAR at the right location.

Comment: Which version of java are you running in CentOS? Show us "java -version"

Answer (score 3):

Java will respond with this error even if it cannot find the file wbc.jar. I am guessing that that is your problem. You might want to see that your are executing the shell script from within the right working directory.

Check to see if you can run wbc.sh from the console or put this in wbc.sh to make sure it searches for the jar in the same directory as the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp `dirname $0`/wbc.jar org.wbc.WBCController
```